# SpringCloudConfig When I use these annotations @RefreshScope @ConfigurationProperties ,I was in trouble

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

#### SpringCloudConfig  trouble

When I use these annotations *@RefreshScope*  *@ConfigurationProperties*, I was in trouble.

```
@Component
@RefreshScope
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config.message")
public class MessageProperties {
    private int max_num;
    private boolean begin;
    private String ding_department;  

    // getter, setter...
}
```

like this ! Config does not work;
but when I use only  @ConfigurationProperties,it works. So What's the use of @RefreshScope. And how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

So when you use "I was in trouble" in stackoveflow you are in trouble that there is high probability no one to answer.

@ConfigurationProperties is used for mapping properties to a POJO, with prefix you start using hierarchical properties structure. SO for example based on your description your code will work if you have the following .yml

```
config:
    message:
      max_num:
      begin:
      ding_department:
```

If for example you use **spring-cloud-config** server to store the configuration properties and spring-boot and want on change on the file the corresponding Bean with injected conf file to be update you add **@RefreshScope**, but even if you do this the bean is not updated you have to call the /refresh url or to trigger event which will refresh it.